# Why is my Update statement not working?

Tags: mysql

Using the following query, I can't figure out why my update is not working.  I'm sure its something stupid, but any help is greatly appreciated:

```
UPDATE Mail
SET From="Spouse"
WHERE ItemNum=9;
```

The Error is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From="Spouse" WHERE ItemNum=9' at line 1
```

The schema of Mail is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Mail` (
  `ItemNum` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Qtr` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `MsgDate` date default NULL,
  `From` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `Message` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ItemNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`From` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Surround it with backticks:

```
UPDATE Mail
SET `From`="Spouse"
WHERE ItemNum=9;
```

Comment: I probably answer two reserved keywords questions a week.  Too bad the parser can't detect and suggest it in the error message...

Comment: @Michael thanks for the adding the link; I was Googling for it as you edited.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I lookup that link so often that when I start typing `mysql` into Google, its the first auto-suggestion.